# How can I share Macbook with a Windows computer on LAN?

Tags: windows, macos, macbook, lan, file-sharing

I have a home wifi network, where I have connected my main desktop running Windows Vista, another laptop using Windows 7 and newly a Macbook Pro running OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

What I need to do is to download some files from the Macbook on my desktop PC. I don't want to use FTP.

**What is the simplest way to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your mac, open System Preferences, under "Internet and Wireless" click Sharing. Click the checkbox beside File Sharing. Click on Options in the right-pane and click "Share files and folders using SMB (Windows)" then make sure your username is checked.

Copy the files you would like to get to the PC into your Public folder (sitting in your Home folder.)

Now on your Windows PC, open "My Computer", click "Network" (or something along those lines, I do not have a copy of Vista around). You should see your Macbook listed in the list of computers on the network that will appear. Open your computer, go into "X's Public folder" (where X is your name) and the files will be there.

To move files from your PC to your mac using this, drop the files into the folder called "Drop Box."

Answer (score 0):

1. on your PC, open a Command Prompt as Admin and type:

   ```
   ipconfig
   ```

   and press "Enter". Take note of you IPV4 Address.
2. On your MBP, at the Desktop or any Finder window, press CMD + K.
   Enter this:

   ```
   Server Address:
   smb://insertYourIPV4AddressHere
   ```
3. Connect with an Admin account